# R + fromJSON - how to send headers info?

Tags: json, r, http-headers, shiny

How can I use `fromJSON` to send header info?

For instance, this is how i request a json data from a server, but the server will require some authentication info from my side.

```
public_key <- 'VzUZFW1cQzP08ovr5auZbXQduzE';
data <- fromJSON(paste('http://127.0.0.1:3000', "/output/data?public_key=", public_key, sep=""),flatten=TRUE)
```

Is it possible with `fromJSON` or other packages?

Comment: The header info doesn't go in the JSON, usually. You usually have a function that sends the headers and body (JSON) as separate parts of the same request.

Comment: @sebastian-c any examples to achieve this?

Comment: Look at this [`httr` tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html). It should at least help you with the idea of how they're separated. Your question is difficult to answer as it stands because its premise is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to include extra http headers in your request,
you should use a different method for getting the url content,
and use fromJSON on the response.

Example using the httr package on the Bing Web Search API:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
QUERY = "your search query here..."
API_KEY = "your api key here...."
url = paste0("https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?",
"mkt=en-US&setLang=en-US&responseFilter=Webpages&textDecorations=false&textFormat=Raw&q=",
QUERY)
httpResponse <- GET(url, add_headers("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = API_KEY), accept_json())
results = fromJSON(content(httpResponse, "text"))
```