# Connect to Rest API in R with key

Tags: r, json, rest, get, tiingo

this is a simple question, but one that I still can't figure out. I want to connect to a REST API with my API key. I've looked through the documentation on `httr`, `jsonlite` and others and still can't figure out how to set the API key.

This is the endpoint - https://api.tiingo.com/tiingo/daily//prices?startDate=2012-1-1&endDate=2016-1-1?

I've tried using the `GET` function on this URL and specify my API key as `key` in the call. I've also tried `api_key = key`. I always get a 401 error back.

Thanks

Comment: see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289067/r-fromjson-how-to-send-headers-info/44715495#44715495

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The API is expecting a `Authorization` header with `Token yOuRAsSiGnEdT0k3n` in it. You should store the token in something like an environment variable so it's not stuck in scripts. I used `TIINGO_TOKEN` and put it into `~/.Renviron`.

You can make a helper function to make the calls less mudane:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(hrbrthemes)

get_prices <- function(ticker, start_date, end_date, token=Sys.getenv("TIINGO_TOKEN")) {

  GET(
    url = sprintf("https://api.tiingo.com/tiingo/daily/%s/prices", ticker),
    query = list(
      startDate = start_date,
      endDate = end_date
    ),
    content_type_json(),
    add_headers(`Authorization` = sprintf("Token %s", token))
  ) -> res

  stop_for_status(res)

  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>%
    fromJSON(flatten=TRUE) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    readr::type_convert()

}
```

Now, you can just pass in parameters:

```
xdf <- get_prices("googl", "2012-1-1", "2016-1-1")

glimpse(xdf)
## Observations: 1,006
## Variables: 13
## $ date        <dttm> 2012-01-03, 2012-01-04, 2012-01-05, 2012-01-06, 2...
## $ close       <dbl> 665.41, 668.28, 659.01, 650.02, 622.46, 623.14, 62...
## $ high        <dbl> 668.15, 670.25, 663.97, 660.00, 647.00, 633.80, 62...
## $ low         <dbl> 652.3700, 660.6200, 656.2300, 649.7900, 621.2300, ...
## $ open        <dbl> 652.94, 665.03, 662.13, 659.15, 646.50, 629.75, 62...
## $ volume      <int> 7345600, 5722200, 6559200, 5380400, 11633500, 8782...
## $ adjClose    <dbl> 333.7352, 335.1747, 330.5253, 326.0164, 312.1937, ...
## $ adjHigh     <dbl> 335.1095, 336.1627, 333.0130, 331.0218, 324.5017, ...
## $ adjLow      <dbl> 327.1950, 331.3328, 329.1310, 325.9010, 311.5768, ...
## $ adjOpen     <dbl> 327.4809, 333.5446, 332.0901, 330.5955, 324.2509, ...
## $ adjVolume   <int> 3676476, 2863963, 3282882, 2692892, 5822572, 43955...
## $ divCash     <dbl> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...
## $ splitFactor <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,...
```

And, it "just works":

```
ggplot(xdf, aes(date, close)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend=date, yend=0), size=0.25) +
  scale_y_comma() +
  theme_ipsum_rc(grid="Y")
```

[image]

You can follow this idiom for the other API endpoints. When done, consider making a package out of it so the community can use what the knowledge you gained.

You can go some extra steps and actually make functions that take date or numeric parameters to actually take those type of R objects and validate them on input, too.

Comment: To set your token in local environment: create a file  '~/.Renviron'  with the text `TIINGO_TOKEN="yOuRAsSiGnEdT0k3n"` and restart R/RStudio. Test that the variable is loaded with the command `Sys.getenv("TIINGO_TOKEN")`

Comment: How to you create a file in /.Renviron

Comment: I get an error with the reader::type_convert() line: Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  date = col_datetime(format = "")
)

Comment: @Cing I'm not going to help triage further in comments. Either start a new question or work on debugging. I also never use this API so I have no idea if it changed.

Comment: Fantastic! worked first time. no edits. Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

The authorization has to added as a request header when invoking a REST api. If you have a username & password, then authorization header would be "username:password".
If it's a single apiKey or accessToken, it could be something like "Bearer "   Replace  with your Api Key.

The request header name should be "Authorization"