# Using API key in R

Tags: r, api

This is a simple question - I am subscribed to FreightWaves' API service and I am trying to retrieve the data using R. I have tried packages such as `httr` and `jsonlite` and followed answers to a similar question here: [Connect to Rest API in R with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169839/connect-to-rest-api-in-r-with-key)

However, I am still getting error 401. Below is a simple version of the test code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

API.KEY <- "My API key"
test <- GET("https://api.freightwaves.com/data/OTRI/ATL/02-20-2019", 
            add_headers(Authorization = API.KEY))
```

Is there anything wrong with the code or it is just something wrong with the API key?

Thanks in advance for the help on this very simple questions.

Comment: The [docs](https://api.freightwaves.com/Help/) say `Authorization: Bearer token-here`. A first interpretation might mean to replace `Bearer token-here` with your API key, which seems reasonable; another interpretation would be to replace `token-here` with the key, suggesting `add_headers(Authorization=paste("Bearer", API.KEY))`. Does that work?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the quick response! I have tried your suggestion by adding "Bearer". However, it still comes back with a 401 error. Does that suggest there might be something wrong with the API key? Thanks so much!

Comment: It may be necessary to reach out to the FreightWaves technical support for this. Since they may not understand R, I find it's good to give examples using the `curl` command-line tool (which suggests doing your testing and confirmation with `curl` before attempting in R). This would translate into `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer API.KEY" https://...`. Once you've confirmed that `curl` also returns 401, then you can go to the tech support with failed `curl` commands and ask them to assist. `curl` is much more understood by non-R users. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the help! Just tried the ```curl``` command-line tool. It gives 500 error - seems like contacting the technical support will be the way. Thanks again for all the useful suggestions!